# Is there any way to hide wp-config.php inside Google App Engine?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, google-app-engine, app.yaml

Just that.

I mean.
I'm a bit noob in GAE. I have a WP web running inside it and I want to protect it a bit. If you are using, for example, Apache, you can put this thing inside the .htaccess file:

```
<Files wp-config.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

and if you try to access to it (directly, www.foo.bar/wp-config.php) you are going to obtain a 403 forbidden error, but I can't find anything similar to get the same results using the app.yaml file.
Is GAE managing differently this kind of attack? Do we have any other option, apart of to change the location of the file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the WordPress docs, you can place the `wp-config.php` file one directory above the equivalent of root or public_html and WordPress core will be able to find it. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

If you have a similar directory structure in GAE (I'm not a user of GAE), try that.

But there are questions as to if this is beneficial: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58391/is-moving-wp-config-outside-the-web-root-really-beneficial